# Rails - How to show an alternative value to the stored value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I have simple select list to mark whether a building is for sale or not:

`<%= select(:building, :for_sale, options_for_select([['Unknown', 'u'], ['Yes', 'y'], ['No', 'n']])) %>`

This is in a New view. It will store for example 'u' when the user selects "Unknown".

However, when the record is created I am directed to the Show view where I see 'u' instead of "Unknown" which is what I would like to see (although I want to store 'u').

What is an efficient way of displaying the user (or Human) text? Maybe it is just a helper method but anything I have come up with seems to be a lot of code for something so simple. Any "The Rails Way" approaches to this?

UPDATE: I am currently doing this in my view:

```
    <% case @building.for_sale when 'u' %>
  Unknown
  <% when 'y'%>
  Yes
  <% when 'n'%>
  No
<% end %>
```

But this seems... well, dumb.

So, question still remains. Is there a best methods way of dealing with this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use the I18n API to do this.

I store every constant under a key in the `config/locales/LOCALE.yml`:

```
en:
  constants:
    u: "Unknown"
    y: "Yes"
    n: "No"
```

Use a helper to retrieve the constants translation:

```
def translate_constant(constant)
  t("constants.#{constant}")
end

# Usage
translate_constant(@building.for_sale)
```

You could also create a helper to create the select options:

```
def constant_options_for_select(options)
  options_for_select(options.map {|option| [translate_constant(option), option] })
end

# Usage
constant_options_for_select(['u', 'y', 'n'])
```

Comment: What an excellent approach! It works perfectly. I do have one question. I can't grasp what "t" does in "t("constants.#{constant}")". Could you clarify.

Comment: It's an alias for `I18n.translate`, along with other niceties, see the source and doc here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/translation_helper.rb#L17